# how to get correlation between tables in python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, correlation

im trying to get correlation between tables(csv),is there any way i can do it in python? if not what should i do to get correlation between my tables?my tables consist price of palm oil,gold,usd-idr,oil and many more. thank you in advance sorry if my question hard to understand!
this is my table,actuaaly all table consist 300 data!

palm oil

```
        month     price    change
0    Aug 1995    616.00         -
1    Sep 1995    586.00   -4.87 %
2    Oct 1995    615.00    4.95 %
3    Nov 1995    607.00   -1.30 %
4    Dec 1995    590.00   -2.80 %
5    Jan 1996    535.00   -9.32 %
6    Feb 1996    518.00   -3.18 %
7    Mar 1996    519.00    0.19 %
8    Apr 1996    562.00    8.29 %
9    May 1996    552.00   -1.78 %
10   Jun 1996    508.00   -7.97 %
11   Jul 1996    476.00   -6.30 %
12   Aug 1996    513.00    7.77 %
13   Sep 1996    545.00    6.24 %
14   Oct 1996    532.00   -2.39 %
15   Nov 1996    550.00    3.38 %
16   Dec 1996    561.00    2.00 %
17   Jan 1997    567.00    1.07 %
18   Feb 1997    580.00    2.29 %
19   Mar 1997    559.00   -3.62 %
20   Apr 1997    562.00    0.54 %
21   May 1997    553.00   -1.60 %
22   Jun 1997    533.00   -3.62 %
23   Jul 1997    498.00   -6.57 %
24   Aug 1997    504.00    1.20 %
25   Sep 1997    525.00    4.17 %
26   Oct 1997    547.00    4.19 %
27   Nov 1997    556.00    1.65 %
28   Dec 1997    566.00    1.80 %
29   Jan 1998    621.00    9.72 %
30   Feb 1998    659.00    6.12 %
31   Mar 1998    671.00    1.82 %
32   Apr 1998    688.00    2.53 %
33   May 1998    705.00    2.47 %
34   Jun 1998    633.00  -10.21 %
35   Jul 1998    661.00    4.42 %
36   Aug 1998    674.00    1.97 %
37   Sep 1998    703.00    4.30 %
38   Oct 1998    694.00   -1.28 %
39   Nov 1998    681.00   -1.87 %
40   Dec 1998    663.00   -2.64 %
41   Jan 1999    632.00   -4.68 %
42   Feb 1999    561.00  -11.23 %
43   Mar 1999    497.00  -11.41 %
44   Apr 1999    509.00    2.41 %
45   May 1999    475.00   -6.68 %
46   Jun 1999    392.00  -17.47 %
47   Jul 1999    319.00  -18.62 %
48   Aug 1999    354.00   10.97 %
49   Sep 1999    388.00    9.60 %
50   Oct 1999    381.00   -1.80 %
```

fosfat

```
           month   price    change
0    Aug 1995   35.00         -
1    Sep 1995   35.00    0.00 %
2    Oct 1995   35.00    0.00 %
3    Nov 1995   35.00    0.00 %
4    Dec 1995   35.00    0.00 %
5    Jan 1996   39.00   11.43 %
6    Feb 1996   39.00    0.00 %
7    Mar 1996   39.00    0.00 %
8    Apr 1996   39.00    0.00 %
9    May 1996   39.00    0.00 %
10   Jun 1996   39.00    0.00 %
11   Jul 1996   39.00    0.00 %
12   Aug 1996   39.00    0.00 %
13   Sep 1996   39.00    0.00 %
14   Oct 1996   39.00    0.00 %
15   Nov 1996   39.00    0.00 %
16   Dec 1996   39.00    0.00 %
17   Jan 1997   41.00    5.13 %
18   Feb 1997   41.00    0.00 %
19   Mar 1997   41.00    0.00 %
20   Apr 1997   41.00    0.00 %
21   May 1997   41.00    0.00 %
22   Jun 1997   41.00    0.00 %
23   Jul 1997   41.00    0.00 %
24   Aug 1997   41.00    0.00 %
25   Sep 1997   41.00    0.00 %
26   Oct 1997   41.00    0.00 %
27   Nov 1997   41.00    0.00 %
28   Dec 1997   41.00    0.00 %
29   Jan 1998   43.00    4.88 %
30   Feb 1998   43.00    0.00 %
31   Mar 1998   43.00    0.00 %
32   Apr 1998   43.00    0.00 %
33   May 1998   43.00    0.00 %
34   Jun 1998   43.00    0.00 %
35   Jul 1998   43.00    0.00 %
36   Aug 1998   43.00    0.00 %
37   Sep 1998   43.00    0.00 %
38   Oct 1998   43.00    0.00 %
39   Nov 1998   43.00    0.00 %
40   Dec 1998   43.00    0.00 %
41   Jan 1999   44.00    2.33 %
42   Feb 1999   44.00    0.00 %
43   Mar 1999   44.00    0.00 %
44   Apr 1999   44.00    0.00 %
45   May 1999   44.00    0.00 %
46   Jun 1999   44.00    0.00 %
47   Jul 1999   44.00    0.00 %
48   Aug 1999   44.00    0.00 %
49   Sep 1999   44.00    0.00 %
50   Oct 1999   44.00    0.00 %
```

usd

```
  Month  Average USD/IDR=  Min USD/IDR=  Max USD/IDR=  Nb of working days
0     7/2020      14531.494955  14265.000000  14785.001747                  23
1     6/2020      14205.574256  14014.550288  14610.003598                  22
2     5/2020      14859.125889  14610.003592  15100.000000                  20
3     4/2020      15815.615970  14875.000000  16678.502195                  20
4     3/2020      15244.035904  14115.002247  16574.997682                  22
5     2/2020      13785.029703  13633.381805  14347.499317                  20
6     1/2020      13725.361768  13595.749887  13940.003573                  22
7    12/2019      14009.235488  13882.499555  14125.002268                  20
8    11/2019      14068.296093  13967.503826  14108.002532                  21
9    10/2019      14118.743665  14012.997204  14227.995963                  23
10    9/2019      14096.884830  13964.996395  14225.107433                  21
11    8/2019      14235.287734  14155.993476  14317.501337                  22
12    7/2019      14035.226772  13939.998218  14141.503586                  23
13    6/2019      14221.194117  14127.783669  14335.000890                  20
14    5/2019      14390.784733  14250.000000  14525.002238                  22
15    4/2019      14147.575701  14042.497778  14233.003686                  20
16    3/2019      14209.025043  14114.908196  14318.998396                  21
17    2/2019      14039.493185  13922.002808  14142.504440                  20
18    1/2019      14159.530333  13910.497911  14463.551812                  22
19   12/2018      14504.478897  14285.448288  14627.948134                  19
20   11/2018      14649.432944  14302.500220  15090.230844                  22
21   10/2018      15176.716431  14910.003446  15291.648448                  23
22    9/2018      14871.692535  14801.996558  14937.547925                  20
23    8/2018      14566.439410  14409.997412  14788.430178                  23
24    7/2018      14407.848955  14324.997879  14517.497858                  22
25    6/2018      14038.132761  13855.002125  14330.000863                  21
26    5/2018      14048.743620  13907.000598  14214.998292                  22
27    4/2018      13814.746362  13750.999110  13939.998366                  20
28    3/2018      13758.855000  13712.998869  13812.366772                  21
29    2/2018      13601.083821  13417.850550  13749.001146                  20
30    1/2018      13375.471706  13293.003949  13481.997513                  22
31   12/2017      13559.118743  13512.999071  13607.004090                  19
32   11/2017      13525.107125  13481.996962  13583.999311                  22
33   10/2017      13529.068445  13453.474166  13630.986644                  22
34    9/2017      13305.576176  13162.498958  13493.003906                  21
35    8/2017      13343.188391  13305.999326  13369.957301                  23
36    7/2017      13347.899864  13300.000000  13407.465825                  21
37    6/2017      13304.348591  13280.605411  13332.997459                  22
38    5/2017      13321.924569  13275.816063  13465.998742                  22
39    4/2017      13304.468824  13256.500470  13329.002745                  18
40    3/2017      13342.194501  13299.438254  13399.772641                  23
41    2/2017      13330.103048  13255.003741  13372.496916                  20
42    1/2017      13360.660718  13250.997284  13527.998089                  22
43   12/2016      13408.157954  13286.498792  13544.998589                  21
44   11/2016      13336.151851  13048.000000  13572.503782                  22
45   10/2016      13024.818815  12977.500000  13077.495923                  21
46    9/2016      13108.745554  12934.001783  13282.594653                  22
47    8/2016      13162.231247  13032.560014  13285.001775                  23
48    7/2016      13119.166314  13045.502168  13205.998735                  21
49    6/2016      13331.162649  13137.035736  13668.999463                  22
50    5/2016      13429.997964  13160.576003  13680.390401                  22
```

gold

```
   month     price    change
0    Aug 1995    383.67         -
1    Sep 1995    383.06   -0.16 %
2    Oct 1995    383.14    0.02 %
3    Nov 1995    385.31    0.57 %
4    Dec 1995    387.44    0.55 %
5    Jan 1996    399.45    3.10 %
6    Feb 1996    404.76    1.33 %
7    Mar 1996    396.21   -2.11 %
8    Apr 1996    392.85   -0.85 %
9    May 1996    391.93   -0.23 %
10   Jun 1996    385.27   -1.70 %
11   Jul 1996    383.47   -0.47 %
12   Aug 1996    387.35    1.01 %
13   Sep 1996    383.14   -1.09 %
14   Oct 1996    381.07   -0.54 %
15   Nov 1996    377.85   -0.84 %
16   Dec 1996    369.00   -2.34 %
17   Jan 1997    355.11   -3.76 %
18   Feb 1997    346.58   -2.40 %
19   Mar 1997    351.81    1.51 %
20   Apr 1997    344.47   -2.09 %
21   May 1997    343.84   -0.18 %
22   Jun 1997    340.76   -0.90 %
23   Jul 1997    324.10   -4.89 %
24   Aug 1997    324.01   -0.03 %
25   Sep 1997    322.82   -0.37 %
26   Oct 1997    324.87    0.64 %
27   Nov 1997    306.04   -5.80 %
28   Dec 1997    288.74   -5.65 %
29   Jan 1998    289.10    0.12 %
30   Feb 1998    297.49    2.90 %
31   Mar 1998    295.94   -0.52 %
32   Apr 1998    308.29    4.17 %
33   May 1998    299.10   -2.98 %
34   Jun 1998    292.32   -2.27 %
35   Jul 1998    292.87    0.19 %
36   Aug 1998    284.11   -2.99 %
37   Sep 1998    288.98    1.71 %
38   Oct 1998    295.93    2.41 %
39   Nov 1998    294.12   -0.61 %
40   Dec 1998    291.68   -0.83 %
41   Jan 1999    287.08   -1.58 %
42   Feb 1999    287.33    0.09 %
43   Mar 1999    285.96   -0.48 %
44   Apr 1999    282.62   -1.17 %
45   May 1999    276.44   -2.19 %
46   Jun 1999    261.31   -5.47 %
47   Jul 1999    256.08   -2.00 %
48   Aug 1999    256.69    0.24 %
49   Sep 1999    264.74    3.14 %
50   Oct 1999    310.72   17.37 %
```

Comment: Which correlation do you want to get? Just comparison? Percentages? Differences in percentages?

Comment: Differences in percentages

Answer (score 0):

The pandas library is perfect for this. You can import your .csv tables using `pd.read_csv`, and set the index to be your date column. This will give you a collection of dataframes, with your dates as the index.

Those separate dataframes can then be combined using the `pd.concat` function. With the sort flag set it will correct any out of order indexes as shown below:

```
>>> dfa = pd.DataFrame([['a',1],['b',2]], index=["thing1", "thing2"], columns=['Value1', 'Value2'])
>>> dfa
       Value1  Value2
thing1      a       1
thing2      b       2

>>> dfb = pd.DataFrame([['g'],['h']], index=["thing2", "thing1"], columns=['Value3'])
>>> dfb
       Value3
thing2      g
thing1      h

>>> pd.concat([dfa,dfb], axis=1, sort=True)
       Value1  Value2 Value3
thing1      a       1      h
thing2      b       2      g
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned: the pandas library can easily do the job.

Start by importing it:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then load your files

```
gold_price = pd.read_csv("your/path/to/gold.csv")
oil_price = pd.read_csv("your/path/to/oil.csv")
```

Afterwards combine your tables:

```
merged_data = pd.concat([gold_price, oil_price], axes=1)
```

From there you can create new columns with combined information:

```
merged_data["gold-oil"] = merged_data["gold-change"] - merged_data["oil-change"]
```

The only thing you need to take care is with your first index row. I think they are not allowed to be named the same. Here you need to rename them, but then it should work just fine.

For more information, you can also check the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/index.html)